# workaround for onShowCustomView

Tags: android, webview, android-videoview

I need to extract the Uri of the currently playing video inside the videoview embedded in a webview . I am able to get this working for android 2.1 to 2.3.7 using the solution provided here

[Android get Video source path from VideoView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321817/android-get-video-source-path-from-videoview).

Unfortunately this does not work in android 3.0 above as the onShowCustomView callback is NOT called in minimised mode .

This issue is also logged here
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36020

Can anybody provide me any alternative workaround to get the videoview uri.

Ok After searching around for a bit (see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3866411/1135101) apparently there is a way to listen for video events via JNI. Now the thing is I am not sure how to write a JNI function that listens for a video event . Can anybody say if this is even possible and how to go about it.

Ok last ditch effort

according to this answer
[Show HTML5 Video Fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319790/show-html5-video-fullscreen)

onShowCustomView is called in fullscreen mode. 
Now the issue is how do i force the video to play in full screen mode when i have no control over the site.

Comment: Is there any other way to know if a video play back event is fired? I was basically using this call back to get the video view of the currently playing video.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)` might help. You will need to filter out video urls and simply return `null`.

Comment: Thanks Mirbek , I will try this out and post the results.

Comment: Well on clicking the video the function is executing but I am not getting the video URLs from there , It is inside the video view which comes as the parameter for the onShowCustomView(View view , )Anyways thanks again for the effort.